# Complex multiple inheritance situation

Tags: c++, oop, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

[class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EZMN.png)

```
class A {public: virtual int func();};
class B: virtual public A {};
class C: virtual public A {};
class D: virtual public C {public: virtual int func();};
class E: public B, public D {}; 
// e is an object of E
e->func(); // this will run func defined in A, not in D
```

I have a multiple inheritance situation as in the above example. How can I implement this to call the most derived method? (To call `func()` implemented in `D`, not in `A`, when I write `e->func()`)

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Can you post some real code?

Comment: `D::func` will be called in this case

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ 2010. I can't post my real code here, because of the confidentiality.

Comment: Please read the MCVE link that you should see at the top of this page now

Comment: @M.M sorry I don't see any link

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DuyMạnhLê "real code" just means code that we can compile to reproduce your problem. It doesn't have to be whatever code you are working on that originally caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When I test your example I get "D" not "A" as you mentioned.

```
class A {public: virtual void func() {std::cout << "A" << std::endl;} };
class B: virtual public A {};
class C: virtual public A {};
class D: virtual public C {public: virtual void func() {std::cout << "D" << std::endl;} };
class E: public B, public D {};

int main()
{
  E e {};
  e.func();
}
```

You have the "Diamond" problem.

```
   A  
 B   D  // only B or D can override A::func()  
   E    // can override A::func()
```

The tip of the Diamond is class A, and it has two classes that derive from it, "B" and "D", on each side of the diamond. Only one of the derived classes that are part of the sides of the diamond can override a virtual function from the tip of the diamond, not both of them (Note that the bottom of the diamond can override, in this case E). In this case is class D which overrides `func`. If class B would override `func` it wouldn't compile. Also if class "B" and "D" don't override anything, in your example, A::func() would be called.

Comment: `D` does override `func`

Comment: Why -1? I stated "D" overrides func.

Comment: For the ones assigning minus, please explain why.

Comment: It is not true that "only one of the derive classes can override..."   Also that hypothetical is not relevant to the question, since the question does actually have only one of the classes overriding (D).  The question involves why the code calls `A::func`, your answer does not address this .

Comment: @M.M When you say "is not true that one of the derived classes can override", when I override with B (having D overriding as well) I get a compile error "no unique final overrider". Even when I test a simpler diamond problem I get the same error. Could you please explain why you are saying that's not true?

Comment: Add a final overrider to E

Comment: @M.M E is not part of the sides of the diamond, is the bottom. I'll clarify this.

Comment: `B` and `C` (and/or `D`) can both override so long as `E` also does

Comment: @M.M If E overrides is no longer diamond problem for that virtual function. Thank you for noting this.

Comment: This all still has nothing to do with the question (in which D overrides and B does not). OP does not report a compilation error; there isn't any "problem" with the structure

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented func in D, that will be called. You can see the running example here

https://ideone.com/kwJubg

```
class A {public: virtual int func(){cout<<"In A";};};
class B: virtual public A {};
class C: virtual public A {};
class D: virtual public C {public: virtual int func(){cout<<"In D";};};
class E: public B, public D {}; 


int main()
{
    E *e = new E();
    e->func();    
    return 0;
}
```